# Best practice to represent a schema with nodes

Tags: views, entities, search

I was wondering what would be the best practise to map my schema within Drupal in order to make them searchable and given some restrictions with the Search API and Views.

My schema is the following:

I want to represent trial cases, their instances and their documents, so I am having let's say 2 nodes:

**Case:**

- case-ID: Text
- case_name: Text
- case_documents: *Entity Reference* to **Case document**
- etc...

**Case document:**

- title
- document_date: Date
- attachment: File
- etc...

I would like to implement a search that allows e.g. to search for the case-id, fields that belong to Case document as well as the full text of the attachments. I am working with Search API, Search API Solr, Search API Attachments and a Solr backend

The above without the requirement to search full texts of the attachments, could be implemented with `Views` and `Entity References`, but when one wants to implement a view over an index, for the moment it simply doesn't work, see [this feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346173)

Is there any alternative way to work around those limitations

Comment: I don't think you need nodes... would non-node entities do it for you?

Comment: @Molot Thank you for your reply. To be honest I am not very familiar with Entities. I tried again today but I couldn't make the entity fields appear under ``admin/config/search/search_api/index/my_index/fields``. Apart from that how could I create a view that searches at the same time the fulltext of an attachment to case_document and fields from case?